# Dynamically read web service structure from a given WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl

Is there a way using Java to read the structure of a `web service` from a given `WSDL`. So basically what I am trying to do is allow the user to enter a `WSDL` into a `text box`, this will then go get the methods within this service and upon clicking on your desired method to call you will be presented with the `inputs` and `outputs` for that web service method.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of libraries to read a WSDL file.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/files/
http://ws.apache.org/woden/index.html

Comment: I have used apache wsdl2js which looks similar to what you suggest. These type of tools are great for calling web services but do not seem to provide anything to get a simple of list of the service inputs and outputs. The problem is I am trying to deal with web services in a dynamic context so therefore need to be able to read out the input and outputs so the user can see them.

Comment: You can try SOAP UI (http://www.soapui.org/). It also does same kind of functionality.You can check its source it is open source. https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui